# What are the things one can do with the internet without the World Wide Web?

Tags: computer-networks

If the question above makes any sense!

Comment: The Internet has existed, in some sense, since the late 1960s; the web only since the early 1990s.

Comment: Here is [the internet before world wide web](https://www.google.com/search?q=internet+before+world+wide+web)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of Internet services people use daily are not based on the WWW. A few examples from the top of my mind: email (POP/IMAP protocols), copy files remotely (FTP), login into a remote server (SSH), instant messaging, file sharing, gaming, newsgroups, anything. The World Wide Web, in this respect, is just one particularly successful Internet service.